# Powershell function doesn't return data

Tags: windows, powershell

Before posting, I looked at [PowerShell function doesn't produce output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980343/powershell-function-doesnt-produce-output) and [Function not Returning Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838782/function-not-returning-data) both links didn't help.

I have a function named getState.  When I call it, nothing is returned.  When I run the debugger, I can see the var $state getting set with "foo" but the getter doesn't return the value of $state.

Here's the code:

```
$Global:state

function setState {
  param(
    [string]$s
  )
  $state = $s
}

function getState {
  return $state
}

setState ("foo")

Write-host getState
```

How can I get the line Write-host getState to show foo?  Thanks!

Comment: The statement `Write-Host getstate` writes getstate.  It will not call the function with that name

Comment: Curious... why cannot one call a function with write-host?

Comment: It is possible: place the function call between parentheses: `Write-Host (getstate)`. Then `getstate` is interpreted first, as function call, and the return value of the function is used as parameter for Write-Host. Without the parentheses `getstate` is just a string parameter for Write-Host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure the global var is used in the functions, specify it as global.

Try this:

```
$Global:state = $null

function setState {
  param(
    [string]$s
  )
  $Global:state = $s
}

function getState {
  return $Global:state
}

setState ("foo")

getState
```